Getting ORA-01722: invalid number error, When executing query
In 3 versions of Orale (11g, 12c, 21c) I create the mytable as follows :
create table mytable (id number, log_time date)

and, then I inserted some data into the table,
insert into mytable values (1, sysdate);
insert into mytable values (2, sysdate);

after that I executed the following query:
select      to_char(log_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI') log_time, count (*)
from        mytable 
group by    to_char(log_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI')
order  by   to_char(log_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI')

But I get ORA-01722: invalid number error.
Is it bug or something else?

I test it by "SQL Developer" and "SQL Navigator"

When you define the alias log_time in the SELECT clause and then use log_time again in the ORDER BY clause then you are referring to the aliased value and not to the underlying table value.
When you use order by to_char(log_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI') the query is effectively the same as:
select      to_char(log_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI') log_time, count (*)
from        mytable 
group by    to_char(log_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI')
order  by   to_char(to_char(mytable.log_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI'), 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI')

Because you are applying TO_CHAR to the aliased value which has already had TO_CHAR applied to it in the SELECT clause. The TO_CHAR function takes either a NUMBER or a DATE as the first argument and the initial TO_CHAR in the SELECT generates a string so there is then an implicit cast for the second TO_CHAR in the ORDER BY clause and that defaults to trying to convert the string to a NUMBER - which fails with the error you are seeing.

To solve it, you want to either just use the alias:
select      to_char(log_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI') log_time, count (*)
from        mytable 
group by    to_char(log_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI')
order  by   log_time

or, explicitly use mytable.log_time to refer to the underlying table value (and not the alias):
select      to_char(log_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI') log_time, count (*)
from        mytable 
group by    to_char(log_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI')
order  by   to_char(mytable.log_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI')

Which, for the sample data, both output:



LOG_TIME
COUNT(*)




20240515 13:21
2



fiddle

the problem is order by clause, write this:
  select to_char(log_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI') log_time, count(*)
    from mytable
group by to_char(log_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI')
order by log_time;


You can order by a string; why would it cause this error?

@AlexPoole Because the log_time in the ORDER BY clause refers to the alias defined in the SELECT clause so you are effectively doing ORDER BY to_char(to_char(mytable.log_time, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI'), 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI').

Right, I’d missed the alias, I read this as just ordering by the original date column instead. An explanation in this answer would have helped *8-)
